# Check which dependency in useEffect was updated

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have this `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTop(t => t + (controller.position.y * tileSize))
  setLeft(l => l + (controller.position.x * tileSize))
}, [controller.position])
```

I want it to only do the addition if the `position` changes. If the `tileSize` changes I just want it to do the multiplication.

I tried putting it in two `useEffect` but then I get the `React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies` warning:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTop(t => t + (controller.position.y * spriteSize))
    setLeft(l => l + (controller.position.x * spriteSize))
}, [controller.position])

useEffect(() => {
    setTop((controller.position.y * spriteSize))
    setLeft((controller.position.x * spriteSize))
}, [spriteSize])
```

What's the best practice in this case?

EDIT:

A reproducible example:

```
const [tileSize, setTileSize] = useState(0)
const controller = {
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    setTop(t => t + (controller.position.y * tileSize))
    setLeft(l => l + (controller.position.x * tileSize))
}, [controller.position])

useEffect(() => {
    setTop((controller.position.y * tileSize))
    setLeft((controller.position.x * tileSize))
}, [tileSize])

const asdf = () => {
    setTileSize(150)
}

return (
    <div onClick={() => asdf()}>click me</div>
)
```

Warning message:

> Line 31:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'tileSize'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also replace multiple useState variables with useReducer if 'setTop' needs the current value of 'tileSize'  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
>
> Line 36:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'controller.position.x' and 'controller.position.y'. Either include them or remove the dependency array                                                                           react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
>     Line 46:  Unreachable code                                                                                                                                                                                                                 no-unreachable

Comment: Did you set `[tileSize]` in second `useEffect` hook?

Comment: @Deda Yes, so it would complain about `position` in one of the `useEffect` hooks and then complain about `tileSize` in the other.

Comment: Please show whole code / reproducible example

Comment: @DennisVash Updated. Both variables are coming from context API hooks. You need that too?

Comment: @DennisVash: Added a reproducible example

Comment: In your example, you cant really change the controller

Comment: @DennisVash: But surely in either case, I must be doing it wrong no? Otherwise it wouldn't have given me warnings (added those too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches, you should peek the most readable one for your use case.

1. As the warning suggests, replace with `useReducer`

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'tileSize'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also replace multiple useState variables with useReducer if 'setTop' needs the current value of 'tileSize'. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

```
const STATE = {
  ADDITION: 'addition',
  MULTIPLICATION: 'multiplication'
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STATE.ADDITION:
      return {
        ...state,
        position: action.position,
        top: state.top + action.position * state.spriteSize
      };
    case STATE.MULTIPLICATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        spriteSize: action.spriteSize,
        top: state.position * action.spriteSize
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Controller({ position, spriteSize }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    top: 0,
    position,
    spriteSize
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: STATE.ADDITION, position });
  }, [position]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: STATE.MULTIPLICATION, spriteSize });
  }, [spriteSize]);

  return <FlexBox>{state.top}</FlexBox>;
}
```

2. You can use references `useRef` and compare with older values
3. If you know what you are doing, just disable the lint warning.

[image: Edit styled-antd-react-starter]